# Google Place API Json data with python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

Update:
after many hours of trial & error.

I was able to get my google Places API json called return data and reduce it  into a list that i can parse.  It most likely is not the best way.  which I know there must be to directly grap the data from the first json data return??????

Here is my code to take return from google api json data.  I take that and reduced fields  and grab the fields I want into shortlist .)

shortlist = []  # list

## results is json data from the google api call.

for place in places_result['results']:

## #define my place id

```
my_place_id = place['place_id']

#define the fields we want sent back to us
my_fields = ['name', 'formatted_phone_number', 'type']

#make a request for the details  drop some fields
place_details = gmaps.place(place_id = my_place_id, fields = my_fields)
```

#save results outside loop in list
    shortlist.append(place_details) # is a list

Sample of Shortlist data:

shortlist data:  just 2 list items just to see format:

{'html_attributions': [], 'result': {'formatted_phone_number': '(760) 864-9900', 'name': 'Palm Greens Cafe', 'types': ['cafe', 'restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'store', 'establishment']}, 'status': 'OK'}
{'html_attributions': [], 'result': {'formatted_phone_number': '(760) 459-4555', 'name': 'Townie Bagels | Bakery | Cafe', 'types': ['bakery', 'grocery_or_supermarket', 'cafe', 'restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'store', 'establishment']}, 'status': 'OK'}

I am able to grab the fields I need in this loop from shortlist

#### works  list of short results

i = 0
for x in  shortlist:
    try:
        find_name = shortlist[i]['result']['name']
        print(find_name)
        i = i+1

```
except(KeyError):
    print('name error')
    i= i+1
    continue
```

#

output from for loop:

Palm Greens Cafe
Townie Bagels | Bakery | Cafe
Starbucks Reserve
McDonald's
Cafe Jasmin
Koffi South Palm Springs
Starbucks
MidMod Café
Gré Coffee House & Art Gallery
Vinny's Italian Ice, Frozen Custard + Ice Cream, Gelato and More
L'Atelier Cafe
Broken Yolk Cafe Palm Springs
Ristretto
Peninsula Pastries Palm Springs
Camelot Internationale Cafe
Rick's Restaurant & Bakery
Starbucks
Swiss Donut
Starbucks
Starbucks

I spent 2 days finally getting this fare.   Just wanted suggestions if there is a more streamline way of doing this?

I could not get the suggested samples to work from reply before this post.

Thanks for the Help.
bill s.

Comment: can you update this with the code you're working with and where specifically you have questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Depending on which library you're using, it may already be parsing the data for you and putting it in a `.json` field. Otherwise, if it doesn't do it for you, you will indeed need to use `json.loads`.
2. Not sure what you mean — most of the time, you would access particular fields in the data, such as: `data.json['result']['name']`

   If you want all the name: value pairs in a dictionary, you can use: `for name, value in data.json['result'].items()`

Comment: thanks. . just relearning    python with json.  so learning curve.. at the moment.